# How do I use callbacks on NVD3 Charts

Tags: nvd3.js

I have been using NVD3 but have decided to add some on-click events.  I found an example using a horizontal bar chart.

```
     vm.qcoptions = {
                chart: {
                    type: 'multiBarHorizontalChart',
                    //type: 'discreteBarChart',
                    height: 450,
                    margin: {
                        top: 20,
                        right: 20,
                        bottom: 50,
                        left: 55
                    },
                    x: function (d) { return d.label; },
                    y: function (d) { return d.value + (1e-10); },
                    showValues: true,
                    valueFormat: function (d) {
                        return d3.format(',.4f')(d);
                    },
                    duration: 500,
                    xAxis: {
                        axisLabel: ''
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        axisLabel: '',
                        axisLabelDistance: -10
                    },
                    callback: function (chart) {
                        chart.multibar.dispatch.on('elementClick', function (e) {
                            console.log('elementClick in callback', e.data);
                        });

                    }
                }
            };
```

The example above works when using the multiBarHorizonatChart, but when I switch to the discreteBarChart it throws this error "Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"  at this line

```
     chart.multibar.dispatch.on('elementClick', function (e) {
```

I have tried to inspect chart and determine what I should in in place of chart.multibar for the bar chart but I am stumped.    Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 1):

You are referring now to the discrete bar chart. You will need to reflect that in the callback function as follows:

```
 chart.discretebar.dispatch.on('elementClick', function (e) {
      console.log('elementClick in callback', e.data);
  });
```

I suggest that you always refer to this [page](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/discreteBarChart) with the extended radio button selected in order to see the appropriate property names.